# Setting Camel load balance route using proxies on Jboss Fuse

Tags: proxy, apache-camel, cxf, load-balancing, jbossfuse

I have a from url, to url and multiple proxies inbetween.
from URL - /banking/optRequest
to URL - /serverSide/acceptOTPRequest 
proxies - 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2

I am expecting something similar to 

    
     / endpoint ip: port//serverSide/acceptOTPRequest ”/>
 / endpoint ip: port//serverSide/acceptOTPRequest ”/>

Now what I want to do is , when someone hits From url , the first request should go to 10.0.0.1 and then redirect it to TO url, second request should go to 10.0.0.2 and then redirect to the TO url.

I understand that Camel lets us load balance the TO endpoint.
my question is Can we use Camel for my requirement and if yes, then how can it be configured.

Comment: How about the load-balancer EIP? http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html. Edit: when reading your question again I now see that you want load-balancing BEFORE entering your route. That seems trickier. Are the requests coming from a web service? Then perhaps this could be of help: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html

Comment: My route will be setup in Jboss Fuse (as a gateway proxy) and the request will come from another container, but yes it will be a webservice call.